# Applying a certain theorem to the definition of (inverse) image of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Theorem $1$ : Let $f$ be a one-to-one function that maps $X$ into $Y$
> and let $A \subseteq X$. If $f(x) \in f(A)$, then $x \in A.$

Another theorem with a proof:

> Theorem $2$ :For all subsets $C$ and $D$ of $Y$, if $C \subseteq D$, then $f^{−1}(C) ⊆ f^{−1}(D)$.
>
> Proof: Suppose $x \in f^{−1}(C)$. Then $f(x) \in C$. Since $C \subseteq D, f(x) \in D$. So $x \in f^{−1}(D)$.

Nothing in the theorem $2$ says the function $f$  is injective. Is the proof still valid? Do we have to worry about the theorem $1$ when doing the proof of theorem $2$? I am not sure if $D$ is the image set of $f^{−1}(D)$.

Comment: Everything written in there is correct. But you have not proved theorem $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 2 holds for non-injective $f$, as stated. The proof of Theorem 2 does not appeal to Theorem 1, only the definition of inverse image and the subset relation. The set $f^{-1}(D)$ is a subset of the domain of $f$, say $X$. It contains all $x \in X$ such that $f$ maps $x$ to a member of $D$. In symbols $f^{-1}(D) = \{x \in X: f(x) \in D \}$.